# My javascript function doesn't fire on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JavaScript function which doesn't fire on page refresh. It works when I navigate to the page from another page, but fails if I refresh the page.

All this function does is assign the height of one element in the page to the height of another element (*If they both exist*).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    if ($(".Video_Pane iframe").length && $(".Image_Pane img").length) {
        $(".Video_Pane iframe").height($(".Image_Pane img").height())
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Console doesn't show any errors regarding this

Comment: Could you set up a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) of a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of the `img` does not imply that it has been loaded (*so you can read its height*). *And refreshing will usually invalidate the cached version of the image so it must be reloaded*.

Try using the `load` event (*on the window object*) and not the `ready`

```
jQuery(window).load(function ($) {
    if ($(".Video_Pane iframe").length && $(".Image_Pane img").length) {
        $(".Video_Pane iframe").height($(".Image_Pane img").height())
    }
})
```

Comment: This surely looks perfect to me, but i was assuming instead of `load`ing  the window, can't it be changed to check the `load` of `$(".Image_Pane img")`?

Comment: @jai it wouldn't be reliable because if the image is cached the handler might not be fired. See the https://api.jquery.com/load-event/ and sepecifically the section about "***Caveats of the load event when used with images***"

Comment: Awesome! missed these caveats. thanks for reminding again.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in you code.
After the last `}` there is a `);` missing.

I just tried it out and its working for me like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    console.log("Hello");
});
```

Comment: I saw the upvoted answer. but he is missing the `);` in his code anyway. Or he maybe forgot to copy it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket.

```
jQuery(document).on('ready',function () {
    if ($(".Video_Pane iframe").length && $(".Image_Pane img").length) {
        $(".Video_Pane iframe").height($(".Image_Pane img").height())
    }
});
```

I would also use .on('ready') rather than .ready.